# Unable to call knative GCP Cloud Run service from another Kubernetes service running in the same cluster

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, istio, gke-networking, knative, google-anthos-service-mesh

I have GKE kubernetes cluster with Cloud Run for **Anthos** enabled (also running **Anthos Service Mesh with Istio**) on it which allows me to host GCP Cloud run container services along with other Kubernetes services in the same cluster.

I am trying to access the Auth Service (running on **Knative Cloud Run for Anthos**) which is in the same namespace from Webapi service (running as Kubernetes Service) but its unable to resolve the auth-service. I had assumed that it would be able to call the actual service via the external name provisioned by Cloud Run/knative but that doesn't seem to work. And I'm invoking the service in my code via the name on default port.

[image]

I am new to the Kubernetes/Istio/Knative world and don't quite understand DNS resolution within this space and so any insights on this would very helpful.

```
>> kubectl describe svc web-api -n backend
Name:              web-api
Namespace:         backend
Labels:            app=web-api
                   service=web-api
Annotations:       cloud.google.com/neg: {"ingress":true}
Selector:          service=web-api
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                10.64.5.37
IPs:               10.64.5.37
Port:              http  51080/TCP
TargetPort:        80/TCP
Endpoints:         10.60.0.243:80
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>

>> kubectl describe svc auth-service -n backend
Name:              auth-service
Namespace:         backend
Labels:            serving.knative.dev/route=auth-service
               serving.knative.dev/service=auth-service
Annotations:       client.knative.dev/user-image:
                 gcr.io/project/team-
app/auth@sha256:7be19cee11b277dd241fd386d4bb83a94d7ab2ed9c9
               cloud.google.com/neg: {"ingress":true}
               run.googleapis.com/client-name: cloud-console
               serving.knative.dev/creator: user@company.com
               serving.knative.dev/lastModifier: user@company.com
Selector:          <none>
Type:              ExternalName
IP Families:       <none>
IP:                
IPs:               <none>
External Name:     knative-local-gateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
Port:              http2  80/TCP
TargetPort:        80/TCP
Endpoints:         <none>
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

Answer (score 2):

It worked by referencing fullhostname http://auth-service.backend.svc.cluster.local in my code appsettings.json file instead of only the external service name which I previously assumed should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look at the Knative Service for a URL, rather than at the Kubernetes Service.

If you run `kubectl describe ksvc -n backend` or even `kubectl get ksvc -n backend`, you should get a URL you can use to reach the Knative Service. (Yes, having two different things named "Service" is confusing. Yes, it's too late to change it.)